# Google fit data is different from device to device with same account

Tags: google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have created a Google Fit application to read/write data from Google Fit. I have two devices linked to the same account, but I cannot see the data added from one device to another.

How is this fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can read global data (Cloud) by adding the .enableServerQueries() in DataReadRequest

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532384/google-fit-sessionsapi-not-returning-all-sessions-in-time-range Am I doing something wrong in my requests?